# String Comparison in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I was fetching data from database using `DataReader` object, but if condition is not getting true in the following code.

I'm trying to make student login page. And I'm posting the sample code where I'm getting the problem.

```
Dim cnn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim str3, str4 As String
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "Select Name,password from Student"
    cmd.Connection = cnn

    cnn.Open()
    Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        str3 = dr.Item(0)
        str4 = dr.Item(1)
        If (String.Equals(str3, TextBox1.Text) And String.Equals(str4, TextBox1.Text)) Then
            Response.Write("Login")
        Else
            Response.Write("NotLogin")
        End If
        Response.Write(str3 & " " & str4 & "<br>")
        Response.Write(TextBox1.Text & " " & TextBox2.Text & "<br>")
    End While

End Sub
```

I have added `Response.Write` statement to check whether the values are correctly fetched from database or not. It turns out that the values were correctly fetched from database and even the value of those textboxes are equal to `dr.Item(0)` and `dr.Item(1)`, but somehow the `If` statement is not working.

Comment: 1. Do not fetch the entire `Student` table from the database - use the `where` clause instead. 2. Never store passwords as plain text. Store a [salted hash](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) instead. 3. Use a local variable inside the `using` statement for sql connection.

Comment: It still doesn't work even when I used local variable inside using statement. I also tried to use WHERE clause earlier, but it is making no difference. 

If condition is getting false eveytime, which I don't understand why.  Even by cross checking by using Response.Write, it turned out that Name and passwords both from textbox and the one which is stored database are equal. And still the if condition is not executing.

Comment: Comparing **strings** is always susceptible to **(a)** different spellings (e.g. capitalized vs. non-capitalized letters), **(b)** leading and/or trailing whitespace(s) and many more issues....